# Arduino as a real device to computer

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, keyboard, mouse

Suppose we have a computer mouse , now when we connect it to a computer then  computer understands it is a mouse which is been connected to it. Same thing happens for keyboard and many other devices. As per my understanding, the mouse has a microcontroller and a TTL serial converter which is programmed a certain way that enable computer's default mouse driver to understand the instructions coming from the connected device.

Let me to talk about one of my projects where I build a device driver for my own device. Like arduino send serial instructions to a port say COM3 and the driver which is a java program reads those instructions and performs accordingly.

As we all know that the arduino library provides support for Mouse and keyboard which works fine. Mouse operations are performed without a custom driver.

Now what I want is when arduino connects to a computer it gets detected as a Joystick or as a pendrive or something like that.

I go through different header files of mouse and keyboard which are present in arduino library but those are very complex and without proper documentation hard to understand.

Can you tell me where I could find study materiel regarding the existing library? Arduino website provides documentations only on different methods not on how it works.

Or if I think of building my own library then how I should start?

One more thing where I can find the information regarding the protocols that a conventional device like mouse, keyboard, pendrive, CD-ROM follows during communication (like the code or the algorithm that is burn into the microcontroller of the device) ?

I know it is a out of the box question but still if you help me, I will be grateful to you.

Comment: Try Google - look for something like Arduino zero HID - I know I have seen people do such things.  (HID is Human Input Device)

Comment: Yes, I know there are several headers including HID for usb interfacing in library but without proper documents difficult to understand. But still I will give a try. If you have any useful links regarding this please mention those in comment

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+zero+hid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per my understanding, the mouse has a microcontroller and a TTL serial converter which is programmed a certain way that enable computer's default mouse driver to understand the instructions coming from the connected device.

No, the mouse's microcontroller *is* a USB device.

> Like arduino send serial instructions to a port say COM3 and the driver which is a java program reads those instructions and performs accordingly.

No, that is the *application* you are talking about. The driver is what you install in Windows to make COM3 appear (that is, in any version of Windows *before* windows 10. Every other operating system, and Windows 10, has the driver built in already).

> Now what I want is when arduino connects to a computer it gets detected as a Joystick or as a pendrive or something like that.

There is no support for that in the Arduino API.

> I go through different header files of mouse and keyboard which are present in arduino library but those are very complex and without proper documentation hard to understand.

Even with proper documentation and understanding of how USB works it's hard to understand.

> Can you tell me where I could find study materiel regarding the existing library? Arduino website provides documentations only on different methods not on how it works.
>
> Or if I think of building my own library then how I should start?

Don't. Trying to do what you want without an in-depth understanding of how USB works is nigh on impossible.  I understand how USB works and struggle with writing USB driver code for microcontrollers.

Instead invest in a device that already does what you want (such as a [Teensy 3.x](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/)), or move away from Arduino and use a professional environment with professional tools and examples to work with.

> One more thing where I can find the information regarding the protocols that a conventional device like mouse, keyboard, pendrive, CD-ROM follows during communication (like the code or the algorithm that is burn into the microcontroller of the device) ?

From the USB Implementer's Forum Inc.

- http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/

> Mouse or pendrive have a special type of microcontroller which are capable of direct communication to pc ? if so then is their any programmable microcontroller in market?

Yes, and there are plenty. Any of the Arduino boards based around the ATMega32U4 (such as the Leonardo) are that kind of microcontroller. The "serial" interface chip on the Uno is that kind of microcontroller (it is capable of being reprogrammed so it looks like a completely different device, and if you google around you will find people that have done it).

> What is the difference between actual driver and my java program which reads COM port?

The driver is what *makes* the COM port. Your program is what *uses* the COM port.

```
[USB device]---->[USB)- Driver -(COM3]<-----[Your program]
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable advice. Couple of more thing to clarify...

Comment: 1) Mouse or pendrive have a special type of microcontroller which are capable of direct communication to pc ? if so then is their any programmable microcontroller in market? 2) What is the difference between actual driver and my java program which reads COM port?

Comment: See my edits...

Comment: you talked about teensy. just guide me whether I am going in right the direction or not. In teensy there is one method namely USB: Raw HID, now if I know how mouse does request and respond and code the teensy as per the mouse communication protocol then I am done

Comment: Raw HID is the basis of the mouse protocol. Over that is laid a "HID Report" that describes the data. The same thing is done for both keyboard and joystick as well. Teensyduino (the Teensy 3.x API) has Mouse, Keyboard, Joystick, etc objects to use: https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_mouse.html

Comment: On top of Raw HID teensy library provide different device support. can you suggest me a web site where I can find communication protocols of different devices. Actually my intention is to design a device which apply brute-force attack for fingerprint devices. Like what we do with keyboard. Computer understand it is a keyboard and the device generates and send different keystrokes.

Comment: I linked it in my answer already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60612/discussion-between-siddhartha-sadhukhan-and-majenko).

Comment: There's always someone who doesn't like answers to questions like "I want to do X incredibly complex thing and I have absolutely no knowledge of understanding of what it is or how it works" that consist mainly of "Don't waste your time, use something more suitable that already does it". I do wish they wouldn't downvote because of that. It really gets my goat (and I have a lot of goat to get...). To whoever downvoted: if you think USB is a simple enough system to just "hack in" some extra functionality without knowing what USB really is (I mean, the OP didn't even know what a driver was) ...

Comment: ... then by all means go ahead and show us how it's done. Don't just go around downvoting answers because you don't agree with the fact that they say not to do something. I have spent years studying USB and still know next to nothing about it. By now I know enough to debug the protocol and trace what is happening, craft descriptors, HID reports, choose endpoint types, etc. Writing the state machines to handle it at the low level required is another matter. It's a nightmare. I am an "expert". This kind of thing is *not* something a beginner can possibly even begin to ...

Comment: ... contemplate attempting. Especially when there are already Arduino-compatible devices that already do what the OP wants.

Comment: sorry but i didn't get your point

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan It's not aimed at you - it's aimed at the n00b that downvoted a perfectly reasonable answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help and like to thank you for that. And I am asking you to send me some other useful links regarding this if you have such.

Comment: You could start here: http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/index.html